# Modal is working fine locally but not working in hosted web

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal, dropdown, web-hosting, pythonanywhere

This is my code which is working fine on localhost but not working on hosting.

```
  {% extends 'layout2.html' %}

  {% block content %}
  
  
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <ol class="col-12 breadcrumb">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Menu</li>
          </ol>
          <div class="col-12">
             <h5 style="font-size: 30px">Menu</h5>
             <hr>
          </div>
      </div>   
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <!-- card start -->
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/cake.jpeg" alt="Cake" style="width:100%;height: 185px;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Cake <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">Rs.250</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">Different varities of cakes. With customized design. You can select you own flavour. Click below to view details and order.</p>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%"> View Details</a>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >Open Modal</button> -->
                    <!-- Modal-1 -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      
                          <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Order cake now.</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <img src="../static/images/cake.jpeg" alt="" style="widows: 100px;height: 185px;">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <address >
                                          <h6> Product Name: Cake</h6> 
                                          <h6> Product Flavour: customized</h6>
                                          <h6> Product category: Best seller</h6>
                                          <hr>
                                          <h6> Availible in both veg and non-veg.</h6>
                                          <h6> Weight of cake is as per customer reqirement.</h6>
                                          <h6> You can place order below.</h6>
                                        </address>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr>
                                  <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                                      {% csrf_token %}
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Customer Name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Email</label>
                                          <input type="email" placeholder="@gmail.com" class="form-control" name="email" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Product name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Cake" value="cake" class="form-control" name="product" readonly>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Select category</label><br>
                                          <select name="category" id="" style="width:180px">
                                              <option value="Veg">Veg</option>
                                              <option value="Non-veg">Non-veg</option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Quantity</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Mobile</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" name="mobile" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Address</label>
                                            <textarea name="address" id="" cols="100" rows="3" style="width:100%"></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Order</button>
                                      </div>
                                  </form> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <!-- Modal-1 -->
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <!-- card end -->
          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/pin.jpg" alt="Cake" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Rolls <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">Rs.20</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">A roll can be served and eaten whole or cut transversely and dressed with filling between the two halves.Click below to order.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" style="width: 100%">Order Now</a>
  
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <!-- Modal-2 -->
                    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      
                          <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Order  now.</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <img src="../static/images/pin.jpg" alt="" style="width: 220px;height: 185px;">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <address >
                                          <h6> Product Name: Rolls</h6> 
                                          <h6> Product Flavour: Regular</h6>
                                          <h6> Product category: Best seller</h6>
                                          <hr>
                                          <h6> Availible in both veg and non-veg.</h6>
                                          <h6> Made with best flour.</h6>
                                          <h6> You can place order below.</h6>
                                        </address>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr>
                                  <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                                      {% csrf_token %}
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Customer Name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Email</label>
                                          <input type="email" placeholder="@gmail.com" class="form-control" name="email" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Product name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="rolls" value="Rolls" class="form-control" name="product" readonly>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Select category</label><br>
                                          <select name="category" id="" style="width:180px">
                                              <option value="Veg">Veg</option>
                                              <option value="Non-veg">Non-veg</option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Quantity</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Mobile</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" name="mobile" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Address</label>
                                            <textarea name="address" id="" cols="100" rows="3" style="width:100%"></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Order</button>
                                      </div>
                                  </form> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <!-- Modal -->
  
  
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/tray.jpeg" alt="Cake" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Cookies <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">Rs.50 per pack</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">These cookie recipes represent the best of the best, including chewy chocolate chip cookies.Click below for order .</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3"  style="width: 100%">Order Now</a>
  
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <!-- Modal-3 -->
                    <div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      
                          <!-- Modal content-->
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Order  now.</h4>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <img src="../static/images/tray.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 220px;height: 185px;">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <address >
                                          <h6> Product Name: Cookies</h6> 
                                          <h6> Product Flavour: Regular-chocolate</h6>
                                          <h6> Product category: Best seller</h6>
                                          <hr>
                                          <h6> Availible in both veg and non-veg.</h6>
                                          <h6> Made with best flour.</h6>
                                          <h6> You can place order below.</h6>
                                        </address>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr>
                                  <form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
                                      {% csrf_token %}
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Customer Name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" name="name" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Email</label>
                                          <input type="email" placeholder="@gmail.com" class="form-control" name="email" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Product name</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="rolls" value="cookies" class="form-control" name="product" readonly>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Select category</label><br>
                                          <select name="category" id="" style="width:180px">
                                              <option value="Veg">Veg</option>
                                              <option value="Non-veg">Non-veg</option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                      
                                      <div class="form-row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6">
                                          <label>Quantity</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity" required>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-md-6"> <label>Mobile</label>
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" name="mobile" required></div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="">Address</label>
                                            <textarea name="address" id="" cols="100" rows="3" style="width:100%"></textarea>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Order</button>
                                      </div>
                                  </form> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <!-- Modal-3 -->
  
  
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>   
      
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/pastries.jpeg" alt="Cake" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Cake <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">$4.99</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order Now</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary offset-sm-1">Comments</a>
  
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/donuts.jpeg " alt="Cake" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Cake <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">$4.99</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order Now</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary offset-sm-1">Comments</a>
  
             
  
  
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/images/breads.jpg" alt="Cake" style="width:100%">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Cake <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-light">$4.99</span></h5>
                    <h2></h2>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Order Now</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary offset-sm-1">Comments</a>
  
                 
  
  
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>   
      
  </div>
   -->
  
  
  
  
  {% endblock %}
```

I have used a bootstrap modal. It is working fine in localhost. But when I host my Django website on pythonanywhere none of the modals is working. The dropdown is also not working. But every bootstrap component other than these two is working fine.

Comment: Without a way to reproduce the bug (a [mcve]), we're blind. We can't inspect the result to tell you what's the source of the bug. From what you describe, it sounds like you're not loading the js part of Bootstrap properly. There might be missing dependencies, or mismatching versions. Your console might be displaying useful debugging or error messages.

Comment: Another possible cause for the bug is you're closing one extra `<div>` in 2 out of 3 `.container`s. Both the modals container and the last one (which is commented) have one `</div>` too many. Using an IDE is very useful at detecting and fixing this type of errors. If using an IDE is not an option, try validating your resulting markup using an HTML online validator.

Comment: this is a link for the hosted web you can see none of the dropdowns is working there:https://mybakeryweb.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You basically included ***a lot of code*** in here which is absolutely irrelevant to the question being asked, because it doesn't contain the actual error you have on your remote. Which outlines the importance of creating a [mcve], making sure it contains the minimal code which reproduces the error. If you think about it, at its core, your mistake was not a coding one, but a copy/pasting one. However, there's one lesson for you here: use ***actual copy/paste*** when asking for help and copy/paste the code which errors, not the one which works. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

There may be problems with bootstrap loading.

After the   `{% block content %}` tag,try copy and paste below CDN of bootstrap.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

If your code work, remove above CDN's and adjust your layout2.html based on bootstrap starter template https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: But  I have already given all CDN in layout2.html. And all the bootstrap components are working fine except modal and dropdowns.

Comment: you did not add {{form}} tag

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where should I add this.

Comment: my bad, I did not see that you are using HTML form.So you can't use that here

Comment: I don't get idea , what do you mean by model here ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button data-target="#myModal" ...>
```

targets a modal with `id="myModal"`, but your modal has `id="#myModal"`.

The ***`#`*** prefix means "***id of***" (it is a CSS selector). Same as **`.modal`** would mean "***`modal` class***".

In conclusion, change `id="#myModal"` to `id="myModal"` and it will work.

My question for you would be: if it works on local, it clearly means on local you have it written correctly. Why would you change it before uploading?
The principle is: ***upload on remote exactly what works on local, without modifying anything!***

Apart from this, note you have a bunch of `404` (not found) errors you should fix.
Console is your friend.

Comment: I have made changes but still, it is the same as before. I hosted same code which is working fine locally. But still getting error.  You may check this link and view page source.  https://mybakeryweb.herokuapp.com/

Comment: @ShantanuMane, you changed it in both `data-target` and the `id`! `data-target` needs to be `#myModal` (it means ***"with id of `myModal`"***). And `id` needs to be `myModal` (without the `#`). They don't need to be the same. `data-target` needs an extra `#`. Look at the examples on Bootstrap website if it's still not clear. And no, it can't be *"the same code which is working fine locally"*. Double check it.